# How to insert an object into postgreSQL db using knex.raw() method?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am looking for a way to insert an object into `postgreSQL` db using knex.raw() method.

Here is my try, it works, but I don't know if it is a best way.

```js
  const newLink = {
    url: 'http://github.com',
    name: 'GitHub',
    description: 'GitHub is awesome',
    rel: '',
    last_update: new Date()
  };
  const columns = Object.keys(newLink);
  const values = Object.values(newLink);
  console.log('columns: ', columns);
  console.log('values: ', values);
  const sql = `
    INSERT INTO link (${columns.map(col => col).join(',')})
    VALUES (${values.map(() => '?').join(',')})
  `;
  console.log('sql: ', sql);
  try {
    const insertObjResp = await knex.raw(sql, values);
    console.log('insertObjResp: ', insertObjResp);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
```

`knex` give me debug information like this:

```
{ method: 'raw',
  sql: '\n    INSERT INTO link (url,name,description,rel,last_update)\n    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)\n  ',
  bindings:
   [ 'http://github.com',
     'GitHub',
     'GitHub is awesome',
     '',
     2018-11-20T04:47:21.085Z ],
  options: {},
  __knexQueryUid: '304fb5e5-9864-4ec6-9a63-1051e8e3c9ad' }
```

Is there an `knex.js` official way to do this work? thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Is there an knex.js official way to do this work? thanks.

Official way is to use `knex.insert()`.

Your code seems correct and there is no better way. Arrays of values and `knex.raw` is a bit inconvenient to use. Of course you should wrap that monster inside a helper function at least.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I prefer use raw `SQL` rather than knex.js api. So I am looking for a raw `SQL` way to insert an object data directly.

Comment: In that case it makes not much sense to use knex and re-implement all query building routines by yourself that knex has already implemented. It will be more powerful to use the db driver directly without knex in your case.